# Multiple AJAX requests to populate form fields?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

Let's say my Backbone.js-based web application has a form containing multiple drop downs, each containing a different type of data, populated via API data.

As I am using Backbone.js, my application logic lives entirely on the client side. Thus, I do not want to populate these drop downs via a typical server-side MVC approach of injecting data into the MVC view via the server side; instead, I want Backbone to retrieve data for these dropdowns.

So, my question is: To populate three different dropdowns, will I perform three different AJAX requests to my API? Example:

1. GET /categories/
2. GET /countries/
3. GET /vehicle/models

Or does it make sense from a RESTful perspective to combine these into some "meta" API method?

Answer (score 0):

I think Backbone is pretty agnostic about this. If you don't mind making three requests, it's certainly okay to do so. If you want to make one call to your API that compiles all three groups of data together and returns them, to be processed on return that is totally legitimate as well.

Comment: From a RESTful perspective, though, does it make sense to compile all three requests into one?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you really want/need to follow RESTful-ness in the strict sense. If it's a one-off thing where you only need to do a single fetch just to populate a drop down I'd consider retrieving the data as a batch. If these categories, countries, and vehicles are used often and as important individual pieces then it makes sense to have a URL for each resource. I'm not sure it's the best practice but as an example, I have individual resource locations for my models in a RESTful way, but I poll on occasion which goes to a different url and grabs a batch of data.

Comment: Yeah, still retaining separate resource locations certainly makes sense. Then I suppose the batch would be an additional resource, itself.